# Convert VARCHAR to SMALLDATETIME as part of UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, data-import

I'm performing a bulk data import on CSV files. In the CSV files, my 'Date' column contains a date in the format 'YYYYDDMMHHMM' (e.g. 200603010929).

As it stands, if I select the 'smalldatetime' when creating the table, the data import will fail with this error:

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 2 (Date).

As I understand it, for it to work the date must be a certain format to work.

Therefore, one idea I have is to import the date values into a field of type VARCHAR, then when the import is finished I want to perform an UPDATE on every row to convert the date to a smalldatetime. This would lengthen the import process, but I think it would be much easier and much faster than attempting to do a find and replace on the CSV data (it's an enormous data set).

So, my question is: 
1) Is this possible? 
2) How do I implement it?

This is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE NYSE
SET [date]=CONVERT(smalldatetime, [date])
```

This fails since the text isn't of the right format. Is it possible to specify the format of the string inside the CONVERT function, or is there some other way?

I appreciate all comments. Thanks.

Comment: Is it really YYYYDDMM and not YYYYMMDD? So 20060301 is January 3rd, not March 1st?

Comment: Yup, it's definitely YYYYDDMMHHMM, January 3rd. 
I have a separate dataset which is in the format YYYDDMM (without time), and that is successfully imported into a table with the DATE SQL data type. 
It's this one which includes the time that I'm having difficulty with.

Comment: Are you sure the YYYYDDMM without time is actually imported correctly? Those are probably swapping the D and M values...

Comment: It is swapping the D and M values for the YYYYDDMM format, but that's not a problem. I don't require the date in any particular format, I just need it as a SQL Date type (or any variant) so that I can perform calculations in Stored Procedures.

Comment: So you don't care if the data is accurate or not? So the user entered March 1st but you interpret it as January 3rd, and that's ok? I'm very confused.

Comment: oh... I see what you mean. The data imports successfully to the DATE object, and when I look at the fields in the database it appears to be in the same format as it was input in (YYYYDDMM). Also, the SQL docs (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) appear to indicate that the default format is YYYY-DD-MM, so I at least hope it's imported correctly. I'll have to verify it for sure though, thanks for raising the concern!

Comment: Where do you see YYYY-DD-MM on that page?

Comment: emm... my eyes have deceived me, actually yeah the default string is what you said, YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: I would suggest telling whoever provides this data to you to stop being stupid about it and supply a valid format. Or pre-process the files with a very simple command-line program before you add SQL Server complexity to it.

Comment: If you read my comments below in the answer, you'll see I actually made a false assumption about the format. Unfortunately, the data provided came without any details of format... stupidity all around! Thanks for the help and advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @s TABLE([date] VARCHAR(20));

INSERT @s SELECT '200603010929';

UPDATE @s SET [date] = CONVERT(CHAR(16), CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, 
  LEFT([date],4) + SUBSTRING([date],7,2) + SUBSTRING([date],5,2) 
  + ' ' + STUFF(RIGHT([date],4),3,0,':')), 120);

SELECT [date], CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, [date]) FROM @s;
```

If it is, in fact, YYYYMMDD, then it is slightly simpler:

```
DECLARE @s TABLE([date] VARCHAR(20));

INSERT @s SELECT '200603010929';

UPDATE @s SET [date] = CONVERT(CHAR(16), CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, 
  LEFT([date],8) + ' ' + STUFF(RIGHT([date],4),3,0,':')), 120);

SELECT [date], CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, [date]) FROM @s;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you have a chance, could you edit the answer to walk-through what is happening? This will help me understand it and check if this will work for my scenario.

Comment: It is basically just pulling apart the pieces of the invalid string to form a valid string. Starting on the second line and working out, it's taking the first 4 characters (2006), then the 7th and 8th characters (01), then the 5th and 6th characters (01). This forms a valid and unambiguous date in YYYYMMDD format. Then on the 3rd line we add a space and inject a colon into the last 4 characters (0929), making it a valid time (09:29) and forming an entire string of 20060103 09:29. This string we can convert to a smalldatetime, but in order to store the string that way, we also need a style.

Comment: I ran the Update statement as you provided, but I got an error, "String or binary data would be truncated". My varchar has a 15 character limit on it currently. I changed the CHAR(16) argument to CHAR(15) - with this it threw the error, "The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.". This time it ran for longer. Would I need to up the limit on my varchar before running this?

Comment: Yes, you'll notice I used varchar(20) for padding. The error you're now getting is because you have at least one date that is NOT in the format you describe. Try `SELECT ... FROM dbo.table WHERE ISDATE(LEFT([date],4) + SUBSTRING([date],7,2) + SUBSTRING([date],5,2) + ' ' + STUFF(RIGHT([date],4),3,0,':')) = 0;`

Comment: I'll up the limit and give it another whirl, and I'll see if I can identify any values which aren't in the correct format. :)

Comment: hmm... I increased the limit but still getting the out-of-range error. It appears on the first line.

Comment: UPDATE NYSE
SET [date]= 
CONVERT(CHAR(16), 
CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, LEFT([date],4) +
 SUBSTRING([date],7,2) +
  SUBSTRING([date],5,2) + ' ' +
   STUFF(RIGHT([date],4),3,0,':')),120);

Comment: I think you missed the part where I said you have some invalid data that my answer can't fix, and you'll have to use the SELECT I posted in a comment to identify it and fix it...

Comment: ah bugger, I ran the query like you said, and lo and behold - I got entries with 201103181314, so basically I have the month and day the wrong way around. The dataset I'm using is stock market data. Each file is grouped by year and in order of date, so I thought it would be a safe assumption that 0301 would be the 3rd of January - the start of the year. It's such a huge dataset that only be executing your command do I realise that it must be the other way around... sorry.

Comment: Yep so I ran the query again (switching around the substring statements for the month and day) and it ran successfully. Thanks again for the help, much appreciated.